# Unwrapping a from IO (a)

Tags: haskell, io-monad

I've been learning Haskell in the last 2 weeks and decided to try challenges at places such as HackerRank.  This has required learning `IO`.  I have read many answers on StackExchange and the general gist is you don't unwrap `IO a`, you just manipulate that data inside the `IO` function.  That being the case what is the point of all the pure functions, if I'm not allowed to send data from main out to them?  Here is some code that reads how many test cases, then for each test case reads *N* ordered pairs.

```
main = do
     test <- getLine
     replicateM (read test) doTest

doTest = do
    query<-getLine
    rs<-replicateM (read query) readPair
    return rs  -- just here to make the file compile

readPair :: IO (Int, Int)
readPair = do
   input <- getLine
   let a = words input in return (read (a!!0) :: Int, read (a!!1) ::Int)
```

At this point I have a `IO [(Int, Int)]` inside of `rs`.  I would like to send that data to this function:

```
validFunction :: [(Int,Int)]->Bool
validFuntion [] = True
validFunction (x:[]) = True
validFunction (x:xs) = (not $ elem (snd x) (fmap snd xs))  && validFunction xs
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to do that.  Any help or suggestions about how to call this function with the data I've read from the user would be appreciated.  Or if I'm going about it from the wrong angle, and pointers on what I should be doing would also work.

---

*Edit:*   From reading lots of other questions on here I now have the general idea that once you're in `IO` you're stuck there.  But what I can't seem to find is the syntax to call a pure function with `IO` data and get back `IO` data.  I've tried some of the following :

```
fmap validFunction [rs] :: IO Bool  -- tried it with just rs without [] as well 
mapM validFunction [rs] :: IO Bool
validFunction rs        :: IO Bool
```

I was able to get this to work:

```
 putStrLn . f . validFunction $ rs
```

though I'm still not clear on why this lets you pass the `IO [(Int, Int)]` to `validFunction`.

Comment: You can't turn `IO a` into `a`. You need to use something like `fmap validFunction` to obtain `IO [(Int,Int)] -> IO Bool` and use that instead. Once you perform IO, you can never have a type which does not show IO is being performed -- by design.

Comment: Yes I understand that from all the answers I've read.  what I can't seem to find is any clear cut example showing the syntax for what I need.  It all seems to involve code that stays inside the main.  I can't find any code that calls a "pure function" from a do block with the syntax you suggested.

Comment: What's the type of `rs`? If it's `IO [(Int, Int)]` then you need `fmap validFunction rs` which has type `IO Bool`.

Comment: Where are you trying to call `validFunction`? `rs` is only bound inside the definition of `doTest`, so you probably want somthin like `fmap validFunction doTest`. If calling it *inside* `doTest`, then replace `return rs` with `fmap validFunction rs`.

Comment: fmap validFunction rs  won't work since fmap changes the [(Int,Int)] i'm expecting into (Int,Int).  However fmap validFunction [rs] :: IO [Bool]  complains that Couldn't match type [] with IO.  Expected type : IO [Bool]  actual type [Bool]

Comment: @chepner: `rs` is already an `[(Int, Int)]`. You mean `return (validFunction rs)`.

Comment: @TonyChamberlain For most HackerRank problems you can solve them with just one built-in `IO` function: `interact :: (String -> String) -> IO ()`. A typical problem can be solved with: `main = interact solveProblem` where you have `solveProblem :: String -> String`. The `interact` function will handle getting all the input from stdin and outputting to stdout.

Comment: When people talk about "processing values inside the IO monad" they *don't* mean that all your functions have to use the IO monad. They mean you put together a bunch of functions, and the *final result* (which is usually called `main`) is in the IO monad.

Answer (score 8):

First of all, if you use `x <- act` in `do`, you essentially have a value. Unless you did something *very* suspicious, `x` isn't a `IO something`, but a `something`: So it's perfectly fine to use

```
foo :: Int -> Char
foo = …

bar :: IO Int
bar = …

fooDo :: IO Char
fooDo = do
   number <- bar
   return (foo number) -- apply foo directly on number
```

However, `IO` is an instance of `Functor`, so we can use `fmap` to *lift* `foo`:

```
liftedFoo :: IO Int -> IO Char
liftedFoo = fmap foo
```

So we could have written `fooDo` like this:

```
fooDo = fmap foo readLn
```

Although it's name is now misleading, it still does the same as before. But let's leave this naming voodoo aside, how would you tackle this? Well, your `doTest` has the correct type:

```
doTest :: IO [(Int, Int)]
doTest = do
    query  <- getLine
    rs     <- replicateM (read query) readPair
    return rs
```

So all that's missing is calling `validFunction`. We can do that like in `fooDo`:

```
doTest :: IO Bool
doTest = do
    query  <- getLine
    rs     <- replicateM (read query) readPair
    return (validFunction rs)
--         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
--         no IO  inside here
--  ^^^^^^ 
--   back 
--  to  IO
```

Or we can `fmap` over another `IO` value, like `replicateM (read query) readPair`:

```
doTest :: IO Bool
doTest = do
    query  <- getLine
    fmap validFunction (replicateM (read query) readPair)
```

The latter is harder to read, though. But you write your <del>`fooDo`</del> `doTest` as you want to `do`.

Comment: Great explanation.  Sadly in all the flailing about I did I actually did return validFunction rs,  but lack of () or $ got me.  I keep forgetting its right associative.

Comment: @TonyChamberlain `return` is a function, not a keyword. That's the key  (heh) one has to keep in mind.