# Haskell: use list generated in IO function in another, non-IO function

Tags: haskell, io, monads, function-call, purely-functional

I am using a `String -> IO [x]` function in order to read in the contents of a file into a list where each element in the list is a word from the file.

However, I would like to use the the `[x]` list as an input for another function. My issue is that I do not understand how to access the basic `[x]` list rather than the `IO [x]` list generated in my initial function. I have been getting around this for testing by using GHCI and using

```
k <- listRead "file.txt"
```

and then using that `k` as input in my next function that only takes a list `[x]` as input.

How can I use the "internal" list `[x]` instead of the returned `IO [x]` that my initial function returns?

Comment: You can't since an `IO a` is not the *result* of an IO operation, it is a "recipe" for an IO operation. You can however use the `k` variable, and thus make a function call.

Comment: See for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/43230210/67579

Answer (score 3):

This is what the `Monad` type class is for.

```
foo :: String -> IO [SomeType]
bar :: [SomeType] -> IO SomeOtherType
```

then

```
baz :: String -> IO SomeOtherType
baz name = foo name >>= bar
```

(or after importing `Control.Monad`, `baz = foo >=> bar`).

If all you have is some function `bar' :: [SomeType] -> SomeOtherType`, then you can define

```
bar :: [SomeType] -> IO SomeOtherType
bar = return . bar'
```

Note you can never actually "get" the value of type `[SomeType]`; you can only create new IO actions that *use* the value once the IO action is executed.

Comment: An alternative to `bar = return . bar'` would be to use the `Functor` instance for `IO`, giving `baz = fmap bar' . foo`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, put that line which you used in GHCi into a `do` block:

```
do
    k <- listRead "file.txt"    
    let r = yourPureFunction k
    return r
```

In [`do` notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/do-notation), for an `x <- mx` line, whenever `mx :: M a` for some Monad `M`, we have `x :: a`.

Thus `yourPureFunction :: a -> b` is applied to the **`a`** argument *on the inside* of **`M`**, and the combined monadic value represented by the `do` block has the type `M b`, because `return` has the type `return :: b -> M b`, and the overall type of a `do` block is the type of its last expression.

The above code happens to really be a higher-level syntax representation of / encodable as / `(return . yourPureFunction) =<< listRead "file.txt"` which is also [the same as](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11249714/849891) `yourPureFunction <$> listRead "file.txt"` (with `(<$>) = fmap`), but that's besides the point.